# Appendix include pdf with working hyperlinks

Tags: graphics, hyperlink, appendix

I'm writing my report in latex and I have a few appendices(written by me also in latex, so source is available).
I want to include these appendices in my report but have the page numbering of my report and of the appendices on the page.
For now my solution was to import a pdf with a scale of 0.8 and it works flawless, see picture[image: Example appendix page]

In this picture you can see the page number of the appendix(20) and the page number of the report(80).
But now i saw that the hyperlinks in this pdf are not working anymore, and I would love for them to work.
I was thinking about importing the tex file but as I wrote all the appendices in different folders with a lot of tex files and their own appendices and image folders I don't really know a way of doing that.

I use one master tex file that imports every other tex file for every report. 
So maybe I can do something with that?

My goal is to include the appendices with working hyperlinks and pagenumbers of original report and appendix itself.

I look forward to a solution! Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\begin{document}[a4paper]

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Plan van Aanpak}
\cleardoublepage
\label{Bijlage:PvA}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},scale=0.95, pages=-]{../PlanVanAanpak/report.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Blub21, can you share your Minimum Working Example piece of code for this?

Comment: I added a MWE. I hope it's enough?

Comment: Short of using Adobe Acrobat to merge, I don't think it is possible to include a PDF with intact hyperlinks. The internal data structure related to the hyperlinks are gone because the PDF is treated as an image.

Comment: @daleif ah that's a shame... then is it possible to import the main.tex files of every report and have the same result as the picture?

Comment: Not understood, that question does not make any sense.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant that i want to import my tex files from the appendices(as i wrote them myself so i have acces to the source) but then still have the TOC and page numbering as if it is it's own report.

But I just googled it and tried somethings but then I came to the problem that the preamble of the appendices gives me a problem... so that's also not possible as far as I'm aware

Comment: Do you want to link to the original document, or just add anchors for all the captions?

Comment: @JohnKormylo preferably the anchors for all the captions. Because that is the same as a reference in the main document right?

Comment: In that case you should save the images using standalone and create new captions.  You can put all the images into one PDF using the [tikz] or [multi=...] options of standalone and the undocumented [page=...] option of \includegraphics.

Answer (score 0):

This only adds links to the original document by page number, assuming it is in the same directory.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{linkpage}

\newcommand{\addlink}{\stepcounter{linkpage}%
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{%
    \path (current page text area.south) ++(0pt,7mm) % offset by trial and error
      node{\href{test5.pdf\#page.\thelinkpage}{\phantom{\thelinkpage}}};}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{linkpage}{0}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\addlink},scale=0.95, pages=-]{test5.pdf}

\end{document}
```